# Display a Float with specified decimal places in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to display the value of a Slider in SwiftUI, but I only want one decimal place to show.

I know how to do this in regular Swift by using %.1f, but that does not work in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is nothing special to do about SwiftUI:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    let myfloat: Float = 1.2345    

    var body: some View {
        let formattedFloat = String(format: "%.1f", myfloat)
        return Text("My Float: \(formattedFloat)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought it should be that simple, I just didn’t know where to put the formatting statement.  In my case I have complex UI and putting the return at the beginning of the first view worked.

Comment: If you ever need it in one line, you can do Text("My Float: \(String(format: "%.1f", myfloat))"), although a little hard to read!

Answer (score 23):

Here's how to do it in one line using SwiftUI. “%.2f” is the format code for floating-point number with two digits after the decimal point

```
Text("You owe me \(balanceDue, specifier: "%.2f") before Tuesday")
```

Answer (score 7):

**iOS 15+**

And this option, if you prefer, uses the floating-point format style:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let myFloat: Float = 1.2345
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(myFloat.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(1)))))
    }
}
```

An example using an extension instead of the above line:

```
extension Float {
    func decimals(_ nbr: Int) -> String {
        String(self.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(nbr))))
    }
}
```

Using the extension:

```
Text(myFloat.decimals(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 15+ you can use the [format](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:format:)) styled text. You don't need custom extensions.

```
Text(balanceDue, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(1)))
```

You can change the `1` in fractionalLength to change the number of decimals.
Updating the `balanceDue` property refreshes the `Text` view.